# A stronger version of Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Claim: $C$ is a simple closed contour, $f$ is continuous at all points interior and on $C$, and $f$ is analytic at all points interior to $C$, then $\int_C f(z)dz = 0$.

To prove this, I suppose we may somehow approach $\int _{C}f(z) dz$ by a sequence contour integrals on closed curve inside $C$, which has value zero by the usual Cauchy Goursat theorem, but can't quite finish the proof.

I saw a similar quesiton [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182561/stronger-version-goursat-theorem), but not quite satisfied with the answer, in particular, the step of bounding the difference of integrals around two different contours. I think the post refers to the ML theorem to bound each contour integrals, but I am not sure how the separate bound for each can be put together to give a bound for the difference.

And ideas or comments are much appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $\int_C f(z)dz$? Presumably, you need some condition on $C$ like rectifiable. If you assume that, the result follows from Caratheodory theorem and the result you want on the unit disc which is an easy consequence of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Conrad how does the result follows from Caratheodory theorem? Prove the result on the unit disc is easy, but since the map in the caratheodory theorem is continuous, and not necessarily differentiable, I do not see how to relate $\oint_C$ and $\oint_{\partial\mathbb{D}}$

Comment: @Caffeine If the boundary $J$ of a simply connected domain $U$ is a rectifiable Jordan curve, any Riemann Map $f :D \to U$ satisfies the property that $f' \in H^1$ (it is an iff actually) and its extension to the unit circle is differentiable ae on the unit circle with the derivatives matching as they should (the non-tangential limit of $f'$ is the same ae as $f'$ taken as one variable function on the unit circle up to the chain rule terms), so it can be used as parametrization of $J$ with which one can carry back any integrals from $J$ to the unit circle

Answer (score 2):

- If $C$ is supposed rectifiable, your claim is correct, but the proof is non-trivial. See for example "The Cauchy-Goursat theorem for rectifiable jordan curves" by Walsh. However, if you know Mergeylan's  theorem (for example, Rudin, in "Real&Complex analysis" provides a proof of it in the last chapter), the result is quite easy to obtain: the claim is trivially true for any polynomial function, and thanks to Mergeylan's theorem, every holomorphic function on $\text{Int}(C)$ continuous on $C$ can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of polynomial on $\text{Int}(C)\cup C$, and the result follows.
- If $C$ is not supposed to be rectifiable, your claim is wrong, as the integral $\int_C f(z)$ could even be undefined (an example is presented here)
- If $C$ is supposed to be rectifiable convex curve, there is an elementary proof sketched here, althought it is quite unelegant.

**Counterexample with a non-rectifiable curve:**

$$\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2\\
\gamma(t)=\left(t,t\sin\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\right)$$

This contour is simple and continuous (adding a path connecting the ends we can
construct also a closed contour). However, $$\int_\gamma zdz$$ does not exist as a limit of riemann sums, as one can show without much effort (hint: consider two suitable Riemann sums and prove that their difference does not go to $0$).

A more pathological counterexample is obtained by choosing as contour a closed osgood curve, which has positive area.

**Proof if $C$ is rectifiable and convex**

If $C$ is rectifiabe, let us call $C_n$ a polygonal path that approximates the curve (and has length $l\le \text{length}(C)$), defined as follows: let $\gamma:[0,1]\to C$ be a parametrization of the contour. Given a partition $\mathcal{P}$of $[0,1]$, the associated polygonal is defined as the polygonal line connecting $\gamma(0),\gamma(t_1),\dots,\gamma(t_{n-1}),\gamma(1)$.

In the following, we will write $\gamma_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ for the curve with domain restricted to $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$, $\gamma(t_i)\to \gamma(t_{i+1})$ to represent the straight segment connecting the two points, and $\Delta_i$ for the length of such segment. We will also associate to $\mathcal{P}$ a Riemann sum $\mathcal{S}=\sum f(\gamma(t_{*}))\cdot (\gamma(t_{k+1})-\gamma(t_k))$ (where $t_*\in [t_i,t_{i+1}]$) Now let us analyze

$$\left|\int_C f(z)dz-\int_{C_n}f(z)dz\right|$$

By triangle inequality, we have

\begin{align*}\left|\int_C f(z)dz-\int_{C_n}f(z)dz\right|&\le\left|\int_C f(z)dz-\mathcal{S}\right|+
\left|\mathcal{S}-\int_{C_n}f(z)dz\right|\\
\left|\mathcal{S}-\int_{C_n}f(z)dz\right|&\le\sum\int_{\gamma(t_i)\to \gamma(t_{i+1})}|f(z)-f(t_*)|dz\\&\le \sum \left(\max_{\gamma(t_i)\to \gamma(t_{i+1})}(f)-
\min_{\gamma(t_i)\to \gamma(t_{i+1})}(f)\right)\Delta_i
\end{align*}

Since $f$ is continuous on $C$, which is bounded and closed, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $C$. Since it is holomorphic in the interior, it is uniformly continuous on $C_n$. Also, since $C$ is rectifiable, we know that $\int_\gamma f-S\to 0$ (since a continuous function on a rectifiable curve is integrable). Thus we can choose a partition with mesh small enough such that:

$$
\left|\int_C f(z)dz-\mathcal{S}\right|\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
\max_{\gamma(t_i)\to \gamma(t_{i+1})}(f)-
\min_{\gamma(t_i)\to \gamma(t_{i+1})}(f)\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2\text{length}(\gamma)}
$$

Thus

$$\left|\int_C f(z)dz-\int_{C_n}f(z)dz\right|\le \varepsilon$$

Since $\varepsilon$ was an arbitrary positive value, their difference must be $0$, i.e.

$$\int_C f(z)dz=\int_{C_n}f(z)dz$$

It remains only to prove that $\int_{C_n}f(z)dz=0$, which is easy: we will prove it by induction on $n$.

$n=3$: left as exercise

$n+1$: we can decompose $\oint C_n$ as

$$\int_{C_n}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma(0)\to \gamma(t_1)\to \gamma(t_2)\to \gamma(0)}f(z)dz+
\int_{\gamma(t_2)\to \dots\to \gamma(1)\to \gamma(t_2)}f(z)dz$$

The first term on the RHS is zero by the base step, the second by induction hypotesis (since it is a polygonal with $n-1$ sides.

Comment: This note pertains to the counterexample with a non-rectifiable curve.  Define $f = t \sin(1/t^2)$.
It is interesting that $\int_0^1 (t + i f)(1 + i f^\prime) dt$ does exist as an improper integral.
However, of the four terms comprising $\int_\gamma zdz$, only three exist as convergent Riemann sums.
The one that does not is $\int_0^1 f df$.  The Riemann sums for that can be made as large positively or negatively as desired.