# Importance of a region being convex

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So I have been reading and solving problems from complex analysis ( A.R Shastri's book), many times we talk of certain results in the case of convex regions. Is there something special about convex regions?

One example is:

> **Cauchy’s Theorem on a Convex Region**: Let U be a convex
>   region and A be a discrete subset of U. Let f be a continuous function
>   on U and complex differentiable on U \ A. Then for any closed contour
>   ω in U we have, $\int_{\omega}f(z)dz=0$

Comment: sometimes it might be easier to give proofs when the set is convex; it allows you to avoid using too much topology. But many results are still true without the convexity assumption (for example i learnt most of my complex analysis from Henri Cartan's book, and convexity was rarely used)

Comment: Convex regions are *simply connected* and Cauchy's theorem does not hold in multply connected domains.

Comment: @MartinR That seems to make sense

Comment: Adding an example to what @peek-a-boo said, see my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610265/a-stronger-version-of-cauchy-goursat-theorem/3613725#3613725 : the claim is true even without the assumption that the region is convex, but the proof is much more difficult and requires stronger theorems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to go a slightly different direction than the comments above and talk about why it's often useful to prove results on convex sets even if they hold on more general regions. The bottom line is that one can often reduce general cases to the convex case. So working on convex sets is a convenient simplification that often ends up implying general cases once enough machinery is developed.

Many results in complex analysis which hold on convex sets $\Omega$, such as Cauchy's theorem, existence of globally defined harmonic conjugates on $\Omega$, that every holomorphic function can be uniformly approximated on compact sets by polynomials on $\Omega$, and existence of logarithms for all nonvanishing holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ actually hold if and only if $\Omega$ is simply-connected. This is a far more general condition than $\Omega$ being convex.

But there are ways one can go from the convex case to the simply-connected case. Of particular note is the Riemann mapping theorem, which states that if $\Omega$ is a simply connected and proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$, there is a biholomorphic map $f$ from $\Omega$ to the unit disk. So if a property is invariant under pre-composition with biholomorphic maps, one can prove the property on convex sets (or just the unit disk) and get the result for all simply connected, proper regions. Another common method one can use to go from the convex case to the simply connected case is the [monodromy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem), which allows one to conclude the existence of an analytic continuation on a simply connected region from analytic continuations along paths (which can often be made from results on open balls).

Another use proving things on convex sets is that one can then lift qualitative versions of some results to compact sets by taking finite covers with balls. One nice use of this technique is to prove versions of [Harnack's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_inequality) on general compact subsets of open regions $\Omega$.

Comment: the only other thing I would add to the very good and comprehensive answer here is that convex sets are easier to recognize and prove that are convex so to speak than say simply connected ones to prove that are simply connected without using a geoemtric property like convexity or starlikeness (or a homeomorphism into such like the RMT nentioned above)